# Confused about Python bytes type

Tags: python, struct

I'm reading a binary file (Python 3) and am trying to convert chunks with the help of the **struct** module.

```
f = open(fn, "rb")
try:
    a=f.read(2)
...
```

When I use :

```
unpack("h",b'\x6b\x0a')
```

it gives me the expected

```
(2667,)
```

But I can't use that syntax on

```
b'6b0a'
```

even though:

```
print(type(b'6b0a'))
print(type(b'\x6b\x0a'))
```

gives the same type:

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
```

What am I mixing up? I think this used to work for me in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b'\x6b\x0a'` is two bytes: 0x6b 0x0a. `b'6b0a'` is four bytes: 0x36 0x62 0x30 0x61.

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify(b'6b0a')
b'k\n'
```

Comment: Ty. How do I convert b'6b0a' into b'\x6b\x0a?

Comment: Ty.   Didn't see that because of the representation as ascii, which was my problem to begin with.   So  import binascii
print(unpack("h", binascii.unhexlify(b'6b0a')))  --> ((2667,)  works.

Answer (score 2):

Inside [bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) you may use *2 methods* for specifying individual bytes:

1. a direct ASCII character, e. g. `b'xyz'`, or
2. an [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (starting with `\`), e.g. `b'\n\123\x56\\'`

Of course, you may combine both methods in one bytes literal, e. g. `b'xy\n\x56abc'`

So your `b'\x6b\x0a'` and `b'6b0a'` a both the *valid* bytes literals - but unfortunately *different:*

- the 1<sup>st</sup>  one consists of `2` bytes (represented as escape sequences `\x6b` and `\x0a`)
- the 2<sup>nd</sup> one consists of `4` bytes (represented as ASCII characters `6`, `b`, `0`, and `a`).

Answer (score 1):

```
\x6b
```

inside a `b''` is the standard [string literal's escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) (allowed in bytes literals, too) for the hexadecimal representation of a *single byte*, while

```
6b
```

inside that bytes literal are *two ASCII characters* representing *two bytes*.

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects):

> Only ASCII characters are permitted in bytes literals (regardless of the declared source code encoding). Any binary
>   values over 127 must be entered into bytes literals using the appropriate escape sequence.
>
> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences
>   of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that 0 <= x < 256.